Handlebars: Using expressions in input data
I want to use Handlebar expressions inside the input data.
The input is like this:
{
  firstname: "Yehuda",
  lastname: "Katz",
  name: "{{firstname}} {{lastname}}"
}

The template:
{{name}}

And the result is of course:
{{firstname}} {{lastname}}

How can I achieve my desired output?
Yehuda Katz

Many thanks!

I can't think of a worthwhile way to do this or a use-case. I think the best approach would be name: "Yehuda Katz".
